# Implementing a protocol with extension in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a `protocol` like so:

```
protocol Parent { 
    associatedtype ValueType

    mutating func foo(value: ValueType) -> Void
}
```

I extend it to another `protocol`:

```
protocol Child: Parent {
    var storedProperty: SomeRandomType? // Need this for the extension!
}
```

And then I implement some default behaviour here like so:

```
extension Child {
    mutating func foo(value: ValueType) -> Void {
        // Ensure storedProperty is initialised and 
        // store value into storedProperty
    }
}
```

Now, in a Test Case

```
struct MyChildImpl: Child {
    typealias ValueType = AnotherRandomType
}
```

At this point, XCode shows me 3 errors:

> - Type 'MyChildImpl' does not conform to protocol 'Child'
> - Type 'MyChildImpl' does not conform to protocol 'Parent'
> - Protocol 'Child' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

This is my first time switching out single-base classes for structs that can have *'mixins'* - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was `Protocol 'Child' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` (the others were fairly trivial to solve) - I resolved to [Type Erasure](https://realm.io/news/tryswift-gwendolyn-weston-type-erasure/) to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Because you assigned the **Parent** protocol in the definition of the **Child** protocol you can't defer protocol compliance in an extension. All protocol compliance must be performed within the block that assigned the protocol.

This has to do with how the compiler (in its current state) checks for protocol compliance. This explains your errors.